# Express JS .ZIP File Downloads

Tags: express, zip

I am creating an express api that will send back a .zip file as a response so that the user can download generated word docs. Is there a way to make it so that the downloaded .zip is not marked as 'suspicious'? I am running behind cloudflare so https is enabled, I am sending what I think are the correct headers. Here is the response code. I am using the archiver package to create the zip file.

Just brainstorming, I am using the generic cloudlfare TLS certificate, should I buy a cert from a public CA?

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=generatedFiles.zip');

// Pipe the zip stream to the response
zip.pipe(res);

// Finalize the zip stream
zip.finalize();
```

Comment: Code looks correct, maybe try from multiple browsers. Check for Server Reputation, CSP, Mime Type and Content-Disposition